# How to access properties of a shape in a shape control in VB.NET at runtime?

Tags: vb.net, shapes

Been trying this for hours and can't get anywhere

I have a page that creates a PictureBox control and draws a RectangleShape around it when it loads. I made a ShapeControl, then loop through drawing the rectangles and adding them to the shape control. That part works fine. I set the "Name" value of the RectangleShape to  a unique value

Now, when I mouseover a PictureBox, I want to make the RectangleShape around that pictureBox visible. But I cant figure out how to access the names RectangleShape inside the ShapeContainer

Code

```
    Dim Cont As New ShapeContainer
    Cont.Name = "rect"
    Cont.Visible = False
    Me.Controls.Add(Cont)

    For i As Integer = 2 To ImagePaths.Length
        'Make a picture box for each image
        Dim pb As New PictureBox

        pb.Name = ImagePaths(i)
        pb.Size = New Size(315, 430)
        pb.Location = New Point(xAxis, yAxis)
        pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
        pb.ImageLocation = ImagePaths(i)

        pb.Tag = indexNum
        indexNum = indexNum + 1

        'add event handlers 
        AddHandler pb.Click, AddressOf pb_Clicked
        AddHandler pb.MouseHover, AddressOf pb_MouseHover
        AddHandler pb.MouseLeave, AddressOf pb_MouseLeave

        'create the selection rectangle here, and make it hidden

        Dim rect As New PowerPacks.RectangleShape
        rect.Location = New Point(pb.Left - 5, pb.Top - 5)
        rect.Size = New Size(pb.Width + 10, pb.Height + 25)
        rect.BorderWidth = 5
        rect.BorderStyle = Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash
        rect.BorderColor = Color.Green
        rect.Name = "rect" & pb.Tag

        Cont.Shapes.Add(rect)

        'put picture box onto form
        Me.Controls.Add(pb)
     Next
```

What would I put in the mousehover and mouseleave handlers to show and hide the rectangle?

Comment: Is there a reason not to add a handler for rect.OnMouseEnter/OnMouseLeave events?

Comment: Have you tried working through the `Controls` collection on the container?